# Showing two mouse cursors?

Tags: mouse, cursor

Whats up with this?:

[image]

When I have a mouse cursor size that is bigger than the actual mouse, this shows up. Please help! It is really annoying and it makes my computer lag. It does not survive a reboot, but right when someone else logs into my computer or I log out and then log back in, it starts again.

Comment: what do you want help with?  A large cursor or two cursors. Since the 2 cursors are aligned, why is it such a problem?  It's like having a different image for the cursor. Just curious.

Comment: @john That is the problem, it is not just a picture, it lags behind the big cursor, it does not disappear when I am watching videos (which is confusing to some streaming networks), and it lags my computer.

Comment: How are you setting the larger cursor, using Mac OS X internal support or using a 3rd party app? What OS version?

Comment: @Josh I set it to a larger cursor in settings

Comment: Do you by chance have a secondary monitor hooked up as well?

Comment: Does this 'feature' survive a reboot?

Comment: Can you create a new user (or Guest user) and tell us if your problem persists?

Comment: @norcaljohnny No, I do not. I do not even have one close by that I can hook up

Comment: @CousinCocaine Yeah, I tried that! It doesn't work! Let me update my question

Answer (score 1):

**One issue could possibly be with the Shake mouse pointer to locate.**

**To turn it off:**

Go into System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Display.

Uncheck the option: Shake mouse pointer to locate.

This might fix it but I'm not sure.

[image]

Comment: It did not work.I tried it

Comment: was it already off? or did you turn it off? If the latter, did you also restart? can you post a screenshot of your Accessibility (Display) screen?

Answer (score 0):

Because this only happens in your user account we can be pretty confident it's being caused by something in your user account. Do you know if you've installed any kind of program that would change the way OS X looks, maybe a cursor program..?

You can try Safe Boot as well by restarting your Mac and holding down the Shift key as it boots. Safe mode uses only required kernel extensions and disables login items, as well as emptying some system caches. If the problem doesn't happen in Safe Boot we'll know for sure that it's one of these issues. If it's a login item you can clear these out in System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items. If it's a cache issue these are usually fixed just by going into Safe Boot. If it's a kext that's a little more complicated but I can show you a method to find out which one it is.

Comment: OP says: "It does not survive a reboot, but right when someone else logs into my computer or I log out and then log back in, it starts again." So I think it is more a global thing, indeed like a misbehaving kernel extension or something similar.

Comment: I must have misunderstood. If it is a misbehaving kernel extension a reinstall of OS X will fix that.

Comment: Ha ha. A reinstall fixes almost every problem.

Comment: If it really is a system kernel extension it will! Reinstalling will only replace the root System where OS X stuff is at so there's no data loss. Your account, files and settings will stay the same. :~)

Comment: @littletinyman what is a 'system kernel extension'?

Comment: I did download a mouse program once... Then I deleted it...

Comment: By system kernel extension I mean a kernel extension that was installed with OS X - it is a part of OS X. Programs aren't supposed to overwrite these but they often do. If you only see it in your user account though then it is just left behind from when you uninstalled that program. Do you remember what that program is called? We can quickly look up what kexts it uses & uninstall them if so